# Web2py not showing Edit or update

Tags: forms, checkbox, edit, web2py

I'm trying to use SQLFORM.grid to show a query of items and have a boolean field that will show up as a checkbox on the form.   I want to be able to check the checkboxes of items i want to move. When submitted have it update on the database as well as perform a special function of copying the selected item's image files into a folder.

My SQLFORM.grid is show up properly with the check box but i can't select the checkbox at all.  As well, i'm not sure how I will have it so that selected items will go through that two step process.

I even set editable = True on SQLFORM.grid
Also set db.items.isMoved.writeable = True

The following is my code:

model:

```
db.define_table('items', 
    Field('itemNumber', 'id'), Field('numSold', 'integer'),                          
    Field('imageName', 'string'), Field('isMoved','boolean')
    Field('timeStamp', 'datetime'))
```

Controller:

```
class VirtualProfitField(object):
  def profit(self):
    return "$" + str(self.items.price * self.items.numSold)

db.items.virtualfields.append(VirtualProfitField())

def display_form():
  default_sort_order = [ebaydb.items.numSold]
  db.items.timeStamp.readable = False
  db.items.imageName.readable = False

  query = (db.items.numSold > 100) 
  default_sort_order = [db.items.numSold]
  form = SQLFORM.grid(query=query, orderby=default_sort_order, create=True, 
    deletable=True, editable=True, maxtextlength=64, paginate=25, csv=False,
    links=[dict(header=T('Profit'),body=lambda row: row.profit), 
    dict(header=T('Image'),
    body = lambda rowB: A(IMG(_src=URL('static', "images/images/"+ 
    rowB.imageName.replace('\\','/')), _width=50, _height=50), _href=URL('static', 
    "images/images/"+ rowB.imageName.replace('\\','/'))))]

   if len(request.args) > 1 and ('edit' in request.args):
     db.items.timeStamp.readable = False
     db.items.imageName.writeable = False

   return dict(form=form)
```

The "edit" or "update" button never shows up.

As well, where and how do I code to move the files selected to another folder?
Will I be able to get the itemNumber and imageName of the items that was checked?

Thank you so much for your help!!

John

PS: I sense Anthony's presence...

Comment: Please reformat your code so it can be read without all the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: So the controller above is def display_form()
In it, i added
    is_this_the_edit_page = 'edit' in request.args
    db.items.imageName.writeable = not is_this_the_edit_page

But it won't work everytime i go into edit.  I print out the request.arg in the html and it is showing "edit" in the list.

Am i suppose to be putting this in a different function separate form my SQLFORM.grid? I placed this before and after SQLFORM.grid but it just won't work.

Comment: That sounds like it should work. You might have to show more code (maybe start a new question). Actually, why not just always set that writable attribute to False -- it is only relevant on Edit forms anyway?

Comment: i've placed the complete function for the view.
You can see i set readable=False already.  This works on the view.  But when i go into edit, I was thinking the if statement will execute and set readable and writeable to False but it doesn't seem to run it.

Comment: The edit form is created and processed by `SQLFORM.grid()`, so you must set any `readable` and `writable` attributes *before* the grid code. Anyway, you might as well just set `writable` to False all the time (it will just be ignored in cases other than the edit form).

Comment: I tried setting the readable and writeable before the grid as well.  It works fine while in the view but when it comes to edit page, it's like it doesn't follow any of the readable and writeable things i wrote.  I tried moving the if statement before and after the grid with the same result.

Comment: I tried to read around but just don't get it when it comes to SQLFORM.grid.  When it goes through it's edit/create does it look at the display_form function again and then this time gets through the if statement or can i expand it on another function like a form_edit?

Comment: It works when I try it. I suggest you start a new question (here or on the web2py Google Group) with some simplified code that demonstrates this specific problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `user_signature=True`, which means create, edit, and delete are disabled unless the user is logged in. If you want non-logged-in users to be able to complete those operations, do `SQLFORM.grid(..., user_signature=False)`.